# How to auto scroll down in WinForms ListView control when update new item?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How to auto scroll down in ListView control when update new item?

I have tried

```
listView1.Focus();
listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
```

but this not working.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Please specify...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try

```
listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: Might I add that this is a winforms only solution, EnsureVisible doesn't exist on the WPF ListView. Only saying because I hit this page from a google search for "WPF ListView auto scroll to bottom".

Comment: Sounds fair enough. Do you have a link to a solution for WPF to help anybody else reaching this answer for the same reason?

Comment: The problem seems to arise from not being able to access the built-in ScrollViewer on the WPF ListView through a property, I am just testing a solution now and will write it up on my blog, link to follow.

Comment: Finally got around to writing that blog post, here's a solution for WPF for info. http://dutton.me.uk/2013/08/13/auto-scrolling-a-wpf-listview-when-a-new-item-is-added/

Comment: @Dutts ironically the more times W P F is mentioned in the comments, the more likely Google is to list this question incorrectly. The search engine isn't terribly context-aware.

Comment: Very true @MarkRansom

Comment: For some reason, `EnsureVisible` did not work for me because ListView control was in an other tab. So i used this instead: `listview1.TopItem = listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1]`

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

`listview1.TopItem = listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1];`

Answer (score 1):

old fashioned solution:

```
 ListView1.SetFocus;
 PostMessage(ListView1.Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

where x is an int, of the item in the list you want to see

```
listView1.Items[x].Focus();
listView1.Items[x].Selected = true;
listView1.EnsureVisible(x);
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe

```
listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected = false;
listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score -2):

Codesleuth's answer of calling EnsureVisible() on the last item in the list only worked for me when called during the forms OnShown() event.

I tried doing it in the constructor, where I was populating my ListView, but nothing happened. Doing it during OnShown() worked a treat, however.

Hope this helps.