# ListView reverse vertical scroll direction

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm filling a ListView on the fly searching for long directory paths.

The ListView updating is quite erratic and the vertical scrollbar goes up, what I'd like the scroll bar to do is scroll down as data is added to the ListView which I hope will stop the flashing of the results.

You can make a ListBox do it with the following code, but I can't find anything similar using a ListView.

```
lstBoxResults2.Items.Add(value);
lstBoxResults2.TopIndex = lstBoxResults2.Items.Count - 1;
lstBoxResults2.Update();
```

I've tried setting the sorting property to ascending or descending but that doesn't work either, I get a weirdness in the results which is paths found are not shown in order of travel i.e.

```
Folder 1...
Folder 2...
Folder 2...
Folder 1...
etc.
```

Code below.

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.GridLines = true;
listView1.Columns.Add("Length", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Path", 1800);

//Test length 150
//static int MAX_DIR_PATH = 150;
static int MAX_DIR_PATH = 260;    

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        btnStop.Enabled = true;
        if (rBtnFolders.Checked == true)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => lblStatus.Text = "Scanning..."));
                foreach (string dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(txtPath.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        //backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                        return;
                        //break;
                    }
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listUpdate1(dir + Environment.NewLine)));
                    try
                    {
                        if (dir.Length >= MAX_DIR_PATH)
                        {
                         this.Invoke(new Action(() => listView1.Items.Add(dir.Length.ToString()).SubItems.Add(dir)));
                            this.Invoke(new Action(() => lblCount.Text = listView1.Items.Count.ToString()));                            }
                        }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        // This code just logs the message and continues to recurse.
                        log.Add(err.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                // This code just logs the message and continues to recurse.
                log.Add(err.Message);
            }
        }
```

On a side note feel free to critique the code, for some reason the above won't search recursively over a raid box attached to my PC (drive M:) but it will on a USB stick attached (J:) If need be I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, I think this might be what you're looking for [How to auto scroll down in WinForms ListView control when update new item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014287/how-to-auto-scroll-down-in-winforms-listview-control-when-update-new-item).

Answer (score 1):

Another thought is to use `Items.Insert()` at insert each item at the top `(Index=0)`.  I did that recently with an event viewer that I created and it seemed to work well.