# Is Anyone have a Listview Renderer for chat

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I need a ListView Renderer for Chat like whatsapp.

when if the new Message comes its automatically scroll down.

Please let me know if have a sample for this.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto scroll down in WinForms ListView control when update new item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014287/how-to-auto-scroll-down-in-winforms-listview-control-when-update-new-item)

Comment: @devNull The question is about Xamarin.Forms and the 'possible duplicate' link you are referring to is about WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom renderer, you can just use a ListView and add some logic to do the scroll for you.

The View.xaml file:

```
<!-- Previous Implementation -->

        <ListView x:Name="MessagesListView"
              Grid.Row="0"
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
              SelectionMode="None"
              SeparatorVisibility="None" />

<!-- Remaining Implementation -->
```

The `x:Name` attribute is the important part, you're going to use that name in the code behind.

And now the View.xaml.cs file:

```
// Previous Implmentation

    /// <summary>
    /// Override of OnAppearing method. Fires as page is appearing.
    /// Good place to set up event handlers.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)MessagesListView.ItemsSource).CollectionChanged += OnListViewCollectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override of OnDisappearing method. Fires as page is disappearing.
    /// Good place to tear down event handlers.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)MessagesListView.ItemsSource).CollectionChanged -= OnListViewCollectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scrolls a the messages listview to the last item whenever
    /// a new message is added to the collection.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnListViewCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myList = ((IEnumerable<Message>)MessagesListView.ItemsSource).ToList();

        // Must be ran on main thread or Android chokes.
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            // For some reason Android requires a small delay or the scroll never happens.
            await Task.Delay(50);
            MessagesListView.ScrollTo(myList.Last(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);
        });
    }

// Remaining Implementation
```

Basically you're going to set an event to fire whenever the ListView's ItemSource changes. In that event, you're going to scroll to the end of the list.

Comment: Hi @Andrew I tried but got this error     "sequence contains no elements in xamarin forms for listview"

Answer (score 0):

You need not a Custom Renderer for chat as a simple ListView will suffice.

Basically, you will bind the ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection so when new messages are added, it will automatically appear on the listview.

Also, you might want to use Infinite Scrolling technique if there are significant number of historical chat messages that you believe user doesn't need/have to view them at once e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DG5Asglf0vU

To scroll to the last message:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
           Listviewname.scrollto(items[count-1], scrolltoposition.end, false)
       });
 });
```

Comment: Yep i know In ObservableCollection can Added Automatically. In Chat i am also using an ObservableCollection and Its Added Automatically But I want show the Last Message Like Whatsapp. When If the new message Comes its shows last message not previous one

Comment: Please mark as answer and upvote if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by scrolling the ListView to its last index after new item added into collection. To scroll the listview you can call LayoutManager.ScrollToRowIndex method by passing itemIndex.

private void InitializeSendCommand()
{
            SendIcon = ImageSource.FromResource("SfListViewSample.Images.SendIcon.png", assembly);
            NewText = "";
            SendCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NewText))
                {
                    MessageInfo.Add(new MessageInfo
                    {

```
                    OutgoingMessageIndicator = ImageSource.FromResource("SfListViewSample.Images.OutgoingIndicatorImage.png", assembly),
                    Text = NewText,
                    TemplateType = TemplateType.OutGoingText,
                    DateTime = string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", DateTime.Now)
                });
                (ListView.LayoutManager asLinearLayout).ScrollToRowIndex(MessageInfo.Count - 1, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ScrollToPosition.Start);
            }
            NewText = null;
        });
```

}

We have attached sample for your reference,

Sample Link:[http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/237037/ze/Sample2053309646][1]

Hope this helps.

**Syncfusion Support Team**